# How to pass an object array from javascript to server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an ajax call form the javascript to MVC controller, passing the array of object to controller action.

**Js Code :**

```
function Constructor(p1, p2) {
    this.foo = p1;
    this.bar = p2;
}

var Obejct_Array = new Array();

Obejct_Array[Obejct_Array.length] = new Constructor("A", "B");
Obejct_Array[Obejct_Array.length] = new Constructor("C", "D");

$.post("/_Controller/_Action", { ObjectArray : Obejct_Array });
```

**C# code**

```
public Class Example
{
  public string foo { get; set; }
  public string bar { get; set; }
  public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

 //Action in Controller
 public void _Action(Example[] ObejctArray)
 {
  //Here the size of ObjectArray is 2 but the properties are all null. Whats the problem ?
 }
```

Both entries from javascript array is passing to the controller`s action method but the property values are showing null. Can anybody tell me the problem ?

Comment: Stringify it, and convert it back on the serverside!

Comment: @adeneo can you please give a an example code

Comment: Not sure how you do it in C#, but Lee Taylor has already posted a link below. In javascript you'd do `JSON.stringify(Obejct_Array)`, and I'm guesing you'd want that as a string since it's an array and all, and just convert it back on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [JSON](http://www.json.org) to do this.  Depending on actual code of your `Constructor` class, this will give you something like this on Javascript side:

```
[{"foo":"A", "bar":"B"}, {"foo":"C", "bar":"D"}]
```

which is the JSON representation of an array of 2 objects with properties `foo` and `bar`.

On the server side, you'll have to convert the JSON structure back to an actual object structure. Surely there are libraries for that (I'm no C# guy, so I don't know any)

Comment: The library in C# to use is JSON.net (http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, you can pass your array data such that it will bind directly to the array parameter in your action method. MVC will expect the data as follows:

```
// in js
var data = {
    // could also put the name of the parameter before each [0/1] index
    "[0].foo": "A",
    "[0].bar": "B",
    "[1].foo": "C",
    "[1].bar": "D"
};

// a js function to put the data in this format:
function (array, prefix) {
    var prefixToUse = prefix || "",
        data = {},
        i, key;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (key in array[i]) {
            // might want to do some filtering here depending on what properties your objects have
            data[prefixToUse + "[" + i + "]." + key] = array[i][key];
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```